# Scheduled event for inactivity in Flex 3 / Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

In a Flex 3 application I need a way to monitor activity/inactivity of a user on the application.

If the user doesn't do anything for 30 min, I just need to show a message for him.

I this possible in Flex 3 / Action Script 3 ?

Or do I need to create a scheduled event which triggers on a given time frame ? Is that possible also ?

Any example is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Reset your counter every time you get a key/mouse event. If counter reaches target, show the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. create a variable to save the last operation time named LAST_OPE_TIME on the application.
2. add mouse event listeners on the stage, and update LAST_OPE_TIME in the events handler.
3. add an ENTER_FRAME event listener on the stage, and in the event handler, use getTimer function to get the current time, and compare to LAST_OPE_TIME.

Comment: A caveat to this method : In some cases, ENTER_FRAME is not dispatched regularly (For example : in some browser, when the app is not in the current tab, ENTER_FRAME doesn't tick). Using a Timer may be better if you want to react to inactivity instantly. Not the case for the OP, since he only want to show a message. Still, +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Aralicia I haven't met the problem you mentioned, so I suggest the OP use ENTER_FARME. Thank you for you advise.